# Doubt regarding Angular SHM

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

In angular SHM (simple harmonic motion), why is the net torque taken about a fixed point (the suspension point in most of the cases)?

Comment: Choose another point and see what you get.  A more involved derivation?

Comment: Perhaps because you consider the rotation around that point and define the angular coordinate around that point?